# Can't print text From Webelement Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Can't figure out how to get this working.
I'm trying to get text from XPath element. Selenium python

**Input**

```
put_action = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="chart"]/svg/g/g[7]/text[1]')
print(time_expented.text)
print(winning_rate.text)
for tx in put_action:
    print(tx.text)
```

**Output**

```
EUR/USD binary signal, expiry at 23:45
Recent EUR/USD binary signals, success rate : 80%
```

**Trying another code**

**Input:**

```
time_expented = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1")
winning_rate = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h2")
put_action = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="chart"]/svg/g/g[7]/text[1]')
print(time_expented.text)
print(winning_rate.text)
    print(put_action.text)
```

**Output:**

```
EUR/USD binary signal, expiry at 0:00
Recent EUR/USD binary signals, success rate : 80%
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mint/Documents/scraper/main.py", line 63, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/mint/Documents/scraper/main.py", line 14, in main
    eurousd()
  File "/home/mint/Documents/scraper/main.py", line 44, in eurousd
    print(put_action.text)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

**This scrape data from here**

Scraped element

[image]

HTML Format

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`svg`, `g`, `rect` etc. are special graph element tag names. They can be treated in a special way, similarly to the element text content.
Instead of

```
put_action = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="chart"]/svg/g/g[7]/text[1]')
```

try this:

```
put_action = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="chart"]/*[name()="svg"]/*[name()="g"]/*[name()="g"][7]/*[name()="text"][1]')
```

Comment: I just corrected YOUR XPath. In order to give you better solution I need to see that page with dev tools so I need a link to that page

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your URL scraping to see the HTML details. Try to identify 2 problems:

- First: Try to *print the xpath* of the main tag <@id="chart"> to *see if the site uses any tricks* to snoop.

```html
put_action = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="chart"]')
print(put_action.text) 
# or print(put_action)
# Run try see must be a kernel must do not find xpath of the main tag or not.
```

or try by replacing tag with the correct *tag of the tag containing id="chart"*. Example: 'div', 'ul', 'li',... etc

```html
put_action = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//'<tag>'[@id="chart"]')
print(put_action.text) 
# or print(put_action)
# Run try see must be a kernel must do not find xpath of the main tag or not.
```

- Second: elements to element

```html
put_action = driver.find_elements_by_xpath
```

to

```html
put_action = driver.find_element_by_xpath
```